# Logs file into a database

Tags: sql, vb.net

So, I have an application where I am able to drop a file into a button and the information will be shown on my database. To make things better I am trying after add something a query will run with an INNER JOIN where there are 2 tables, one of them will simply save the files info and the other one will save the date and time of that added file. I already have the LogsFile method:

```
Private Sub LogFileAdicionados()
    Dim LogsFile As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    Dim logtext As String = lblName.Text
    Dim logtext2 As String = lblSize.Text
    Dim vt As String = "The file " & logtext & " com " & logtext2 & " KB " & "was added at " & TimeOfDay & " in " & Date.Today & "." & vbCrLf
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LogsFile + "\LogsAdded.txt", vt, True)
End Sub
```

So what should I do to INSERT the data and time values onto the Logs table?

Comment: `what should I do to INSERT the data and time values onto the Logs table` right now I do not see anything related to `sql` or even an attempt. Google would be your best bet, look up table creation, connecting to `sql` instances, using parameters and stored procedures. Without anything to go on we can't help much as this would require one of us to basically write an example application in which we will not do. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As Zaggler pointed out, you need at least to attempt to do it yourself in order to post more meaningful question. However I'm going to set you on the track and see what happen...

First you need an approach on how to interact with your database. I'll show you how to do it with ADO.NET data objects, but keep in mind that there are other tools/frameworks to interact with a DB storage.
Next you need the connection string to your database. You can find hundreds of examples [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Then you can do some fun stuff, like:

```
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("connection string to your DB goes here")
        Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Logs (fields definition) VALUES" + vt
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Basically this outlining saving data to a SQL DB, using ADO.NET data objects.

Comment: You should use an SQL parameter for the value to avoid SQL injection attacks.